# How can I check a DropDownList for containing item in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am transfering my program from a WPF to ASP.Net.

I want to check a `DropDownList` if it contains a Item which I did in WPF this way.

```
else if (!_cbSlot3.Items.Contains("Jump") && !_cbSlot4.Items.Contains("Jump"))
{
    foreach (string s in Stats2)
    {
        _cbSlot3.Items.Add(s);
        _cbSlot4.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Simply it checks if it does not contain `Jump` in the 2 DropDown's.

Visual Studio tells me that it want a `ListItem` instead of a string now when doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inbuilt function for `DropDownList`, those are `FindByValue` and `FindByText`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use it like this - `_cbSlot3.Items.FindByValue("jump") != null` or  `_cbSlot3.Items.FindByText("jump") != null` .

Comment: yeah also what I did notice :) but thx for the reply :) still having trouble with my postback resetting my external class cuz I call it in as a new instance still trying to remember what to do there.

Answer (score 1):

[ListControl.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `ListItemCollection`, so to check for values you indeed need to use property of `ListItem` similar to:

```
 !_cbSlot3.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Contains(v => v.Value == "Jump")
```

Note that `ListItemCollection.Contains` searches for value and text of `ListItem` where you seem to want to check just value. See [ListItem.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ca35ayd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for comparison details.